# How to get back value from model function

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi i'm getting back an empty value from the below code. I do not know what went wrong. Can some1 help me plz ?

```
class GeneratorsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_generator, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  # GET /generators
  # GET /generators.json
  def index
    @generators = Generator.all
  end

  # GET /generators/1
  # GET /generators/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /generators/new
  def new
    @generator = Generator.new
  end

  # GET /generators/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /generators
  # POST /generators.json
  def create    
    @generator = Generator.new(generator_params)

    @generator.choice = params[:choice]
    if params[:choice] == 'Randomly'
        @generator.random_generate(params[:primer_length],params[:random_primer_generated],params[:c_primer])
    #elsif params[:choice] == 'No_of_ATGC'
    #    @generator.no_ATGC
    #elsif params[:choice] == 'Seating'
    #    @generator.seating
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @generator.save
        format.html { redirect_to @generator, notice: 'Generator was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @generator }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @generator.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /generators/1
  # PATCH/PUT /generators/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @generator.update(generator_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @generator, notice: 'Generator was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @generator.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /generators/1
  # DELETE /generators/1.json
  def destroy
    @generator.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to generators_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_generator
      @generator = Generator.find(params[:id])
    end

    def generator_params
      params.require(:generator).permit(:primer_length, :choice, :random_primer_generated)
    end
end
```

In my model

```
class Generator < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :choice, :primer_length, :random_primer_generated, :genome_sample
      belongs_to :result

      def random_generate(primer_length,random_primer_generated,c_primer)
         length = primer_length
         length=length.to_i
            chars = 'ATGC'
            seq = ''
            length.times { seq << chars[rand(chars.size)] }
           self.random_primer_generated = seq
           c_primer =Bio::Sequence::NA.new(self.random_primer_generated.reverse)
           self.c_primer=c_primer.complement.upcase
      end 
end
```

There's no error but i get back null value for the random_primer_generated and c_primer attribute

Comment: an example of the models could be useful

Comment: sorry i editted it. PLease save me T.T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `generator_params` instead of `params` in your create action.

This is beyond the scope of the question but a refactored generator could be:

```
  def random_generate(primer_length)
     chars = 'ATGC'
     seq = ''
     primer_length.to_i.times { seq << chars[rand(chars.size)] }
     self.random_primer_generated = seq
     c_primer =Bio::Sequence::NA.new(self.random_primer_generated.reverse)
     self.c_primer=c_primer.complement.upcase
  end
```

And you should try that it actually works in a `rails console` like this for example:

```
g = Generator.new
g.random_generate(4)
```

Unit test the Generator model is even better then just use the rails console ;)

Answer (score 1):

I bet you are forgetting to save the Generator instances to the database after calling `random_generate`.

If that is not the problem, could you post a snippet of interaction in the Rails console showing how you try to set those two attributes and how they end up being nil?  It is hard to tell from the information provided exactly how you are reproducing the problem.  A console session would clear things up and it would allow you to test your models separately from the controllers.

Comment: i give them only the primer_length not the random_primer_generated. I wan the function defined in my model ( random_generate) to give the value for the attribute random_primer_generated. But it's returning nil. 

How to post the snippet of interaction ?

Comment: You could post it in a gist at https://gist.github.com/ or just edit your original question.